# Почему блок не помещается в экран?

Tags: html, css

Почему у меня так криво отображается блок на адаптиве?

Должно быть так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А получается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам сайт ilyin1ib.beget.tech

Код jsfiddle.net/vy4mhun6/

Comment: 1. Приведите код в вопрос. 2. Что конкретно не получается? А то, это выглядит, как - сделай за меня!

Answer (score 1):

Ради интереса сверстал этот макет -

ссылка на проверенную вёрстку: https://facejsonserver.000webhostapp.com/

```js
let select = `<ul class="choose">
  <li class="result">Choose lang</li>
  <li>rus <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/555/555451.png" alt=""></li>
  <li>eng <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/555/555613.png" alt=""></li>
  <li>deo <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/206/206626.png" alt=""></li>
</ul>`;

document.querySelector(".select").innerHTML = select;

let result = document.querySelector(".result");
let ul = document.querySelector(".choose");

ul.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  result.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  width: 660px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 290px;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrapper_header {
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

ul:hover {
  height: 106px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 4px 6px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:not(:first-child):hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

ul li img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.name input,
.sub {
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex .select {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
}

.flex input {
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.flex ul {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.selector {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.selector span {
  color: red;
}

.sub {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: #428a60;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.sub_wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

form input {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.sub_wrapper .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 65%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.item {
  width: 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/kBBWMC0/pill.png), url(https://i.ibb.co/QjMFXcP/background.jpg);
  background-size: 75% 50%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 30px 130px, 0 0;
}

@media (max-width: 670px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    width: 350px;
    padding: 30px 0;
  }
  .wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="outer">
        <p class="wrapper_header">Сделай шаг <br> к выздоровлению</p>
        <form action="">
          <div class="selector">ваше <span>имя</span></div>
          <p class="name">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Алексей">
          </p>

          <div class="selector">ваш <span>телефон</span></div>
          <p class="flex">
            <input type="tel" placeholder="+7(800)800 80 80">
            <span class="select"></span>
          </p>

          <p class="sub_wrapper">
            <input type="submit" value="Заказать" class="sub">
            <span class="icon"> ➝ </span>
          </p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- wrapper -->
  </div>
  <!-- grid -->
</div>
<!-- центрирующий элемент-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Надпись reduslim и eco находятся в одном диве? Если да-то нужно менять ширину этого дива